# Does MFC provide a quick way to throw text on the clipboard?

Tags: mfc, clipboard

The add-to-clip-board code we have in our code base is quite low-level - allocating global memory and so on. For the simple case I just want to put some plain text on the clipboard, are there any routines which can wrap all that stuff?

An example is that CRichEditCtrl has Copy() & Cut() methods which automatically put the current selection on the clipboard. Does MFC make this kind of functionality available in isolation?

**Update**: Created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265382/win32-copying-string-to-clipboard-only-one-character-written-when-pasted) based on mwigdahl's response

Comment: Only one I know of is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sze892zx%28VS.80%29.aspx which I assume is what you are already using. Even if not it hardly gives you much extra as you almost certainly still need to to call GlobalAlloc or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but it's not that hard to wrap it yourself.  Adapted from [Frost Code](http://www.frostcode.info/common-articles/write-to-windows-clipboard.html) (and untested):

```
void SetClipboardText(CString & szData)
{
    HGLOBAL h;
    LPTSTR arr;

    h=GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, szData.GetLength()+1);
    arr=(LPTSTR)GlobalLock(h);
    strcpy_s((char*)arr, szData.GetLength()+1, szData.GetBuffer());
    szData.ReleaseBuffer();
    GlobalUnlock(h);

    ::OpenClipboard (NULL);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, h);
    CloseClipboard();
}
```

Comment: I tweaked your code to compile and not crash on Unicode (minor) and got another problem. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265382/win32-copying-string-to-clipboard-only-one-character-written-when-pasted