# Copying string to clipboard, only one character written when pasted

Tags: winapi

I was basic some code off this [code](http://www.frostcode.info/common-articles/write-to-windows-clipboard.html), also mentioned in my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253476/does-mfc-provide-a-quick-way-to-throw-text-on-the-clipboard). That version forces the character type to `char*`, which breaks compilation on my unicode project. So I made the following tweaks:

```
void SetClipboardText(CString & szData)
{
    HGLOBAL h;
    LPTSTR arr;

    size_t bytes = (szData.GetLength()+1)*sizeof(TCHAR);
    h=GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, bytes);
    arr=(LPTSTR)GlobalLock(h);
    ZeroMemory(arr,bytes);
    _tcscpy_s(arr, szData.GetLength()+1, szData);
    szData.ReleaseBuffer();
    GlobalUnlock(h);

    ::OpenClipboard (NULL);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, h);
    CloseClipboard();
}
```

The copying looks fine - running in a debugger Visual Studio tells me `arr` contains the copied string as expected.
But When I then paste into any application, only the first character is pasted.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Unicode comment in the prior question's comment is telling.  If you have a wide character string with a low-ASCII character, in UTF-16 it's going to be encoded as the low-ASCII byte followed by a NULL.  [Use CF_UNICODETEXT instead of CF_TEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649013%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Good catch, I never thought of that 2nd-byte-is-zero case.